# Win2019 print server no printers show in Network

Tags: windows-server-2019, print-server

I have an old Win2012 print server which serves printers to users. I'm adding a new Win2019 print server to the domain in order to migrate printers from the old print server to the newer one, and eventually decomm the old server.

I've exported the printers from the old server and imported them to new server sucecssfully, and I see them in the new print server's Print Management app. I have right-clicked and chosen "List in Directory" for some printers for testing and they show up in Windows 10 "Add a printer or scanner" dialog.

However, if you try to directly browse the new print server via \ps02.mydomain.com, there are no printers shown. If I do the same with \ps01.mydomain.com, I see all the published printers.

How would I get printers from ps02 to show up when you browse to that server under Networks?

Comment: Do you see the shares when you run the `NET SHARE` command?

Comment: Did you share the printers on the new server? Do you see any shares on the new server? Is the Server service running on the new server?

Comment: NET SHARE on the old printer server (2012) shows the printers. Same on new (2019) server does not show any printers. On the new server, the printers are all in Print Management app. For printers I want to share, "Share this printer" is checked, as is "List in the directory." This doesn't have any effect...they don't show in NET SHARE or if I browse to \\ps02, which is the server's name.

Comment: I've confirmed the Server service is running.